# cannot attach database OS error

Tags: sql, database

Does anybody know what this error is? I cant seem to attach the database...
Unable to open physical file ....... Operating System Error 5:"5 (failed to retrieve text for this error. Reason:15105)".(MS SQL Server error:5120)
Could it be an OS problem (Windows not being genuine)? or Authentication?...........................................................................................................................................................................................

[image: db]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MSSQL Management Studio probably does not have permissions to access that folder. Try placing it where MSSQL stores the master, msdb and model databases. I cannot remember the exact path, but it's somewhere in "C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server...". Just try searching for master.mdf in the Program Files directory.

Comment: Worked!... Although why cant I attach it from another folder? I don't want to keep the database in C: .....

Comment: You just need to give MSSQL Management Studio permission to access the alternative path. You'll have to google for the answer on this one, I can't remember exactly how to proceed.